# it showing error in GridView that is does not contain a definition for 'gv_RowUpdating no extension method 'gv_RowUpdating'

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

i have add link button in GridView , but in RowUpdaing method it is showing error , that is, does not contain a definition for 'gvReportCrime_RowUpdating' and no extension method 'gvReportCrime_RowUpdating' accepting a first argument of type does not contain a definition for 'gvReportCrime_RowUpdating' and no extension method 'gvReportCrime_RowUpdating' accepting a first argument of type ... here is my Admin.aspx page , and Admin.aspx.cs page code

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvReportCrime" runat="server" DataKeyNames="id" OnPageIndexChanging="gvReportCrime_PageIndexChanging" OnRowCancelingEdit="gvReportCrime_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowDeleting="gvReportCrime_RowDeleting" OnRowEditing="gvReportCrime_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="gvReportCrime_RowUpdating"  BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" GridLines="Vertical" AutoGenerateColumns="False">

                             <Columns>
                                 <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />
                                 <asp:BoundField DataField="CNIC" HeaderText="CNIC" />
                                 <asp:BoundField DataField="Phone1" HeaderText="Phone1" />
                                 <asp:BoundField DataField="Phone2" HeaderText="Phone2" />
                                 <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" />
                                 <asp:BoundField DataField="Gender" HeaderText="Gender" />
                                 <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" />
                                 <asp:BoundField DataField="Address" HeaderText="Address" />
                                 <asp:BoundField DataField="CrimeType" HeaderText="CrimeType" />
                                 <asp:BoundField DataField="CrimeDetail" HeaderText="CrimeDetail" />
                                     <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true" />  
                                     <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="true" />
                             </Columns>

                        </asp:GridView>



      private void BindData()
    {
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection();
        conn.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("Select * from reportCrime", conn);
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        conn.Close();
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            gvReportCrime.DataSource = ds;
            gvReportCrime.DataBind();
        }

        else
        {
            ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(ds.Tables[0].NewRow());
            gvReportCrime.DataSource = ds;
            gvReportCrime.DataBind();
            int columncount = gvReportCrime.Rows[0].Cells.Count;
            gvReportCrime.Rows[0].Cells.Clear();
            gvReportCrime.Rows[0].Cells.Add(new TableCell());
            gvReportCrime.Rows[0].Cells[0].ColumnSpan = columncount;
            gvReportCrime.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text = "No Records Found";
        }
    }





    protected void gvReportcrime_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
  {
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection();
        String CNIC = Convert.ToString(gvReportCrime.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow) gvReportCrime.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        Label lblID = (Label)row.FindControl("lblID");
        //TextBox txtname=(TextBox)gr.cell[].control[];  
        TextBox txtName = (TextBox)row.Cells[0].Controls[0];
        TextBox txtPhone1 = (TextBox)row.Cells[1].Controls[0];
        TextBox textPhone2 = (TextBox)row.Cells[2].Controls[0];
        TextBox textEmail = (TextBox)row.Cells[3].Controls[0];
        TextBox textGemder = (TextBox)row.Cells[4].Controls[0];
        TextBox textAddress = (TextBox)row.Cells[5].Controls[0];
        TextBox textCity = (TextBox)row.Cells[6].Controls[0];
        TextBox textCrimeType = (TextBox)row.Cells[7].Controls[0];
        TextBox textCrimeDetail = (TextBox)row.Cells[8].Controls[0];

        //TextBox textadd = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtadd");  
        //TextBox textc = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtc");  
        gvReportCrime.EditIndex = -1;
        conn.Open();
        //SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM reportcrime", conn);  
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("update reportcrime set Name='" + Name + "',Phone1='" + Phone1 + "',Phone2='" + Phone2 + "',Email='" + Email + "',Gender='" + Gender + "',City='" + City + "',Address='" + Address + "',CrimeType='" + CrimeType + "',CrimeDetail='" + CrimeDetail + "' WHERE CNIC = '" + CNIC + "'", conn);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
        BindData();
        gvReportCrime.DataBind();  
    }
```

Comment: first argument of type.. ?

Comment: first argument of type 'ASP.admin_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)